# How do I embed a webgl build game that I created in unity into a website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, unity-webgl

okay, so I have a game that I developed in unity. I exported it as a WebGL build now wanted to know, would it possible to embed this game into a website? At this point in time, I only know how to create web forms using ASP.net in c# with visual studio and I would like to be able to embed my game into a website I created.

Answer (score 1):

well.
first Upload Unity WebGL outputs to your web server,
and in your website, Simply just create iframe and put your webgl index.html in the iframe.